# Regarding Jquery validation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I put the jquery validation on select filed and i take field  name is name="course[]". I take it in array because I want to store multiple selected option in table but when i use this name in validation that time my validation is not working on select field can anyone suggest me any solution.

My jquery code is here:-

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#formValidate").validate({
         rules: {
         course:{
                   required: true
               },
            messages: {
               course:{
                  required: "Enter a username";
               },
            errorElement : 'div',
           errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
             var placement = $(element).data('error');
             if (placement) {
               $(placement).append(error)
             } else {
               error.insertAfter(element);
             }
             }
              });
             </script>
```

my html field code is here:-

```
 <form class="formValidate" id="formValidate" action="" method="POST">
 <select multiple id="course" name="course[]">
 <option value="Php">PHP</option>
 <option value="ruby">RUBY</option>
 <option value="wordpress">WORDPRESS</option>
 <option value="java">java</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is

Comment: @shivani : check my below answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your field name is `course[]`, not `course`. Therefore you need to wrap the object key in quotes and include the braces.

Also note that your code has some errors; you've placed a `;` within an object which is a syntax error, and you're missing a closing `}`.

```js
$("#formValidate").validate({
  rules: {
    'course[]': { // note the quotes and braces here
      required: true
    },
    messages: {
      course: {
        required: "Enter a username"
      },
      errorElement: 'div',
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var placement = $(element).data('error');
        if (placement) {
          $(placement).append(error)
        } else {
          error.insertAfter(element);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="formValidate" id="formValidate" action="" method="POST">
  <select multiple id="course" name="course[]">
    <option value="Php">PHP</option>
    <option value="ruby">RUBY</option>
    <option value="wordpress">WORDPRESS</option>
    <option value="java">java</option>
 </select>
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use array add field name with `[]` along with `'` or `"`

```
 ("#formValidate").validate({
     rules: {
     "course[]":{
               required: true
           },
        messages: {
           "course[]":{
              required: "Enter a username";
           },
        errorElement : 'div',
       errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         var placement = $(element).data('error');
         if (placement) {
           $(placement).append(error)
         } else {
           error.insertAfter(element);
         }
         }
          });
         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my updated code below, it will print validation message `'Enter a username'` which not showing on other user's answers as they missed a closing `}` in `rules`  in their code.

```
$("#formValidate").validate({

    rules: {
      'course[]': { required: true }
    },

    messages: {
      'course[]': { required: 'Enter a username' },
      errorElement: 'div',
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

        var placement = $(element).data('error');

        if (placement) {
          $(placement).append(error);
        } else {
          error.insertAfter(element);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```